# How to merge images into one file in a defined order

Tags: r

I have around 100 images(png). Instead of doing that manually, I want to put them beside each other (12 images per line) in one single pdf in a defined order (based on file names).

Does anybody have any suggestion?

I tried according to what Thomas told me below, it paste them beside with a black margin, how can I remove that?

```
setwd(workingDir);
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="*.png", all.files=T, full.names=T)
filelist <- lapply(files, readPNG)
names(filelist) <- paste0(basename((files)))
list2env(filelist, envir=.GlobalEnv)


par(mar=rep(0,4))
layout(matrix(1:length(names(filelist)), ncol=15, byrow=TRUE))

for(i in 1:length(names(filelist))) {
  img <- readPNG(names(filelist[i]))
  plot(NA,xlim=0:1,ylim=0:1,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
  rasterImage(img,0,0,1,1)
}


dev.print(pdf, "output.pdf")
```

Comment: To be honest no idea how to do that. I thought using "par" defined how many images in a line...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854424/786542) works for me (use [`magick` package](https://rdrr.io/cran/magick/man/animation.html))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can plot them all together using the `rasterImage` function and the **png** package. Here's a simple showing how to read in a PNG and then plot it (a bunch of times).

```
library("png") # for reading in PNGs

# example image
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

# setup plot
par(mar=rep(0,4)) # no margins

# layout the plots into a matrix w/ 12 columns, by row
layout(matrix(1:120, ncol=12, byrow=TRUE))

# do the plotting
for(i in 1:120) {
    plot(NA,xlim=0:1,ylim=0:1,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n")
    rasterImage(img,0,0,1,1)
}

# write to PDF
dev.print(pdf, "output.pdf")
```

You would need to modify this slightly so that it calls each image object, rather than just plotting `img` over and over again.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried what you told me but I get an error. I updated my post. would you please have a look?

Comment: @EpiMan When calling `plot`, specify `bty="n"` (meaning boxtype = none).

Comment: @Thomas, Thank you for this. I found it working for me after tweaking a loop to fit all my images.  I just want to ask what does the plot(NA,...) doing there. The RasterImagwe wont work without it. can I have a dumb down explaination please?

Answer (score 8):

Note that the solution outlined by Thomas introduces some whitespace into the multipane image not present in the source image. Adding the arguments `xaxs = 'i'` and `yaxs='i'` into `plot()` will remove it.

```
library("png") # for reading in PNGs

# example image
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

# setup plot
dev.off()
par(mai=rep(0,4)) # no margins

# layout the plots into a matrix w/ 12 columns, by row
layout(matrix(1:120, ncol=12, byrow=TRUE))

# do the plotting
for(i in 1:120) {
  plot(NA,xlim=0:1,ylim=0:1,bty="n",axes=0,xaxs = 'i',yaxs='i')
  rasterImage(img,0,0,1,1)
}

# write to PDF
dev.print(pdf, "output.pdf")
```

[image: result image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just want to put a bunch of PNG images into a PDF file, one image per page, for quick and easy viewing of them using a PDF reader.  Here is how I did it, building on the above solution, and shrinking the image if necessary to fit the output PDF (but preserving the aspect ratio).  This allows you to easily bundle PNG images of various sizes.

```
library(png)
# Define a function to get the xright and ytop arguments for rasterImage()
get.raster.image.area.scaling <- function(pngfile) {
  imga <- attr(readPNG(pngfile, info=TRUE), "info")
  img.width <- imga$dim[1] / imga$dpi[1]  # width of PNG image in inches
  img.height <- imga$dim[2] / imga$dpi[2]  # height of PNG image in inches
  img.aspect <- img.height/img.width  # aspect ratio of PNG image
  ri <- list()
  if(img.width > my.width || img.height > my.height) {
    # shrink to fit output device page
    diff.width <- img.width - my.width
    diff.height <- img.height - my.height
    if(diff.width >= diff.height) {
      # shrink to fit width
      ri$width <- 1.0  # xright for rasterImage (fraction of device area)
      new.height <- img.aspect * my.width # (in)
      ri$height <- new.height/my.height  # ytop for rasterImage (fraction of device area)
    } else if(diff.height > diff.width) {
      # shrink to fit height
      ri$height <- 1.0  # ytop for rasterImage (fraction of device area)
      new.width <- my.height / img.aspect # (in)
      ri$width <- new.width/my.width  # xright for rasterImage (fraction of device area)
    } else stop("need to debug unexpected situation\n")
  } else {
    # no shrinking of PNG image needed
    ri$width <- img.width / my.width
    ri$height <- img.height / my.height
  }
  return(ri)
}  # end of get.raster.image.area.scaling()

pngfiles <- c("yourfile1.png", "yourfile2.png", "yourfile3.png")
num.png <- length(pngfiles)
my.width <- 8  # dimensions of desired PDF device output (in)
my.height <- 10
pdf(file = "testplot.pdf", width=my.width, height=my.height, pointsize=12)
par(mai=rep(0,4)) # no margins
for(i in 1:num.png) {
  img <- readPNG(pngfiles[i], native=TRUE)
  ri <- get.raster.image.area.scaling(pngfiles[i])
  plot(NA, xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1, bty="n", axes=0, xaxs = 'i', yaxs='i')
  rasterImage(img, 0, 0, ri$width, ri$height)
}
dev.off()
```