# How to convert all pages of a pdf into a single page pdf document in R

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

I have tried exploring pdftools. It does have a pdf_combine() function which stitches multiple pdf to one. However, It doesn't help combine multiple pages of a pdf document into one page.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to combine a subset of pages, you could use the `pdftools` library and the `pdf_split` command. First, split the original PDF and save the result to your working directory.  Then, you could make a list of the split files with `list.files` and recombine them in the same directory with a new name.

```
library(pdftools)
setwd("Z:/mypath/folder")  # put all your PDFs here; initially to include one file that is to be split
pdf_split('originalfile.pdf') # split pages into multiple files
myfiles<-list.files(pattern = "pdf")  # get a list of the split files
myfiles<-myfiles[1:4]  # select the first four pages, for example
pdf_combine(myfiles,output = "joined.pdf")  # join them
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP was asking for. I believe they wanted the images on a single sheet, not multiple sheets within one PDF.

I found a work around whereby I created my intermediary images as .png files and then combined them using the method described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682712/how-to-merge-images-into-one-file-in-a-defined-order).